# ClassFormatError when using @Secured and @RequestMapping on same method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having a weird error thrown when I try to use `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize` in a `@Controller` method already annotated with `@RequestMapping`. It gives me the following error when I try to start the application (using spring STS 2.8.1 with vFabric 2.6.1 on win 7 32 bits, with both springframework and spring security 3.1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file com/dnp/web/controllers/HomeController
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 43 more
```

And the controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }
}
```

I've got no clue on why this error is thrown, and haven't found anything on the internet about it. Also, secured annotations on the service layer work without problems.

PD: The full application trace is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VxdYPDXL, and the main sections of both security and servlet context are here: http://pastebin.com/cva5VgkH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was being caused by some weird conflict between Spring AOP and AspectJ compile-time weaving on the same methods: I'm using an aspect to advise controller method invocations and it was being compile-time woven in the controllers. So, the solution was just to disable the AspectJ compilation and now it's working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

@rabusmar, i got this link from SpringForum
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109850-RequestMapping-and-PreAuthorize-not-compatible

Seems like the PreAuthorize and Request Mapping are not compatiable. They have given a solution at the end of the page. Just give a try.

Moreover the ClassFormatError comes when a class already instrumented by one annotation is being instrumented again by another annotation, in your case the HomeController may already been instrumented by PreAuthorize and again by RequestMapping or vice versa and that is the reason you are getting the ClassFormatError.

You can try the solution give in that spring forum link that i have given above.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar ClassFormatError in some groovy code. But the error message didn't say which method name&signature was duplicated.

I found what was wrong by running the command below:

```
javap -private -c io.cloudsoft.mapr.m3.MasterNodeImpl | grep -A 1 '^$' | sort | uniq -c | less
```

This found all the method signatures (which are always preceded by a blank line in my javap output), and then counts unique occurrences so I could see which method signature was duplicated. I hope others fine that useful.

(For those interested, my problem was strange behaviour of groovy's @InheritConstructors, which somehow added a no-arg constructor twice).